# I don't know why my device keeps disconnecting in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
I/utter_travelin(31159): Clamp target GC heap from 53MB to 48MB
I/utter_travelin(31159): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 64KB allocation
I/utter_travelin(31159): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/utter_travelin(31159): Clamp target GC heap from 53MB to 48MB
I/utter_travelin(31159): Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 20(712B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 47MB/48MB, paused 5us total 7.039ms
I/utter_travelin(31159): WaitForGcToComplete blocked Background on HeapTrim for 6.238ms
W/utter_travelin(31159): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 65552 byte allocation with 53984 free bytes and 52KB until OOM, target footprint 50331648, growth limit 50331648" (VmSize 9934428 kB)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(31159): Process: com.example.flutter_traveling, PID: 31159
E/AndroidRuntime(31159): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 65552 byte allocation with 53984 free bytes and 52KB until OOM, target footprint 50331648, growth limit 50331648
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.<init>(FastXmlSerializer.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.<init>(FastXmlSerializer.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:778)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$900(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:647)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:666)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:585)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.MethodCallHandlerImpl$1.run(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(31159):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/utter_travelin(31159): Clamp target GC heap from 53MB to 48MB
W/System  (31159): A resource failed to call close.
I/Process (31159): Sending signal. PID: 31159 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Device keeps disconnecting from flutter, I don't know why, please help
In the Android simulator, this phenomenon is occurring continuously, and in ios, it works without any problem.

Comment: Some times its happen when your emulator's containing disk has out of space.Make some available space of disk may resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error Log shows

> Throwing OutOfMemoryError

If you run your project on an emulator please clean it or uninstall your app.