# Client device keeps getting disconnected in Star network

Tags: android, flutter, google-nearby

I am building an Android mobile app using Google Nearby (v19.0.0) to connect a bunch of client devices to a server one in a star formation. One of my users is testing everything with one server tablet and 4 client devices. All the devices have the latest version of Google Play Services. And after being connected to the server for a couple minutes, they keep being disconnected, receiving the `onDisconnected` callback in the `ConnectionLifecycleCallback` and I don't know why, and I can't figure out why these disconnections even happen.

Note that all devices are static and within 1 meter of each other, and they are all connected to the same Wi-fi router. So really I don't get why they keep getting disconnected.

Any idea on how to even troubleshoot what is happening and why those disconnections happen?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an issue with the package/plugin usage, normally Bluetooth will connect constantly without being disconnected unless one of the devices is out of service. And the factor for services can be varied:

- Memory
- GPS Network
- The package/plugin itself
- Human Interrupt on the device
- Out of range

But I found some of the issues are out of memory, perhaps it is worth checking this out. >
[I don't know why my device keeps disconnecting in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418937/i-dont-know-why-my-device-keeps-disconnecting-in-flutter)